# python - Error entering data into the database

Tags: python, mysql-python

A new member has been registered in the database, but when entering the profile modification page and adding other information, it is registered in a new row and not in the same information as the registered member.

**register new member** :

```
 def add_users(self):
            add_fullname = self.line_fullname.text()
            add_username = self.line_username.text()
            add_Email = self.line_email.text()
            add_password = self.line_password.text()
            add_phone = self.line_telephon.text()
            add_birthday = self.dateofbirth.text()
            add_profession = self.line_profession.text()
            add_Country = self.line_country.text()
            add_keyone = self.keyone.text()
            add_keytwo = self.keytwo.text()
            add_newpassword = self.new_pwd.text()
    
            self.cur.execute(''' SELECT add_username FROM users=add_username''')
            data = self.cur.fetchall()
                
                self.cur.execute(''' INSERT INTO users(add_fullname, 
    add_username, add_Email, add_password, add_phone, 
    add_birthday, add_profession, add_Country, add_keyone, add_keytwo, add_newpassword) 
    VALUE (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s  ) ''',
    (add_fullname, add_username, add_Email, add_password, add_phone, add_birthday, 
add_profession, add_Country, add_keyone, add_keytwo, add_newpassword))
                    self.mysql_db.commit()
                    self.line_fullname.clear()
                    self.line_username.clear()
                    self.line_email.clear()
                    self.line_password.clear()
```

this code for **fill profile** :

```
def save_profil(self):
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(6)
        add_fullname = self.line_fullname.text()
        add_Email = self.line_email.text()
        add_phone = self.line_telephon.text()
        add_birthday = self.dateofbirth.text()
        add_profession = self.line_profession.text()
        add_Country = self.line_country.text()
        add_keyone = self.keyone.text()
        add_keytwo = self.keytwo.text()
        add_newpassword = self.new_pwd.text()
        self.cur.execute(''' INSERT INTO users(add_fullname, add_Email, add_phone, add_birthday, add_profession, 
add_Country, add_keyone, add_keytwo, add_newpassword) 
                                    VALUE (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s  ) ''',
                         (add_fullname, add_Email, 
add_phone, add_birthday, add_profession,
                          add_Country, add_keyone, add_keytwo, add_newpassword))
        self.mysql_db.commit()
        print("profil edited")
```

[image: This is the registration information and is registered successfully]

[image: This is how it appears in the database]

[image: Now when you go to the profile page to fill in the rest of the information]

[image: This is the error, this new information is not recorded in the same row as the member's information, but another new row is reserved]

Answer (score -1):

You should use UPDATE instead of INSERT in the "save_profil" function if the profile already exists.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

You will also need to indicate which user should be updated in

> WHERE condition

I would also advise you to read the user ID or another unique key you have defined in your table. So you can update the correct user.

Ex:

```py
def save_profil(self):
    self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(6)
    add_fullname = self.line_fullname.text()
    add_Email = self.line_email.text()
    add_phone = self.line_telephon.text()
    add_birthday = self.dateofbirth.text()
    add_profession = self.line_profession.text()
    add_Country = self.line_country.text()
    add_keyone = self.keyone.text()
    add_keytwo = self.keytwo.text()
    add_newpassword = self.new_pwd.text()

    query = "UPDATE users SET add_fullname=%s, add_Email=%s, add_phone=%s, add_birthday=%s, add_profession=%s, add_Country=%s, add_keyone=%s, add_keytwo=%s, add_newpassword= %s WHERE (UNIQUE_KEY = %s)"
    data = (add_fullname, add_Email,add_phone, add_birthday, add_profession,add_Country, add_keyone, add_keytwo, add_newpassword, UNIQUE_KEY_VALUE)

    self.cur.execute(query,data)

    self.mysql_db.commit()
    print("profil edited")
```

Note that UNIQUE_KEY and UNIQUE_KEY_VALUE are suggestions, you must define these values according to your model.
As I can see in the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9XXl.png) that shows the database, you can use the "id" to know which user should be updated.For this case, UNIQUE_KEY would be replaced by `id`, and UNIQUE_KEY_VALUE would be the user id that needs to be updated, in your example it would be 14, but you need to get that value inside your function, just like you got the other values.

Comment: thnk you sir for reply : but i have error if put this modifie : 
self.cur.execute(''' UPDATE users SET add_fullname = 'add_fullname') 
                                    WHERE condition; ''',
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: **WHERE condition** shoul be updated according the user id you need to save. I updated the answer, see above please.

Comment: @mgaliazzi Never concatenate to form an SQL query since the SW will be susceptible to SQL Injection attacks, you must use the placeholders

Comment: @eyllanesc  what you mean with concatenate? Is " val1='{}' ".format(val1) not a placeholder syntax?

Comment: @mgaliazzi Doing `val1='{}' ".format(val1)` is concatenated and is susceptible to SQL Injection

Comment: Great, I just read about it, and I will change that in my projects too. Thank you @eyllanesc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you give me examples of what can be written in UNIQUE_KEY and UNIQUE_KEY_VALUE ?

Comment: @OualidBoukouja I just updated the answer according to @eyllanesc comment, and also exemplified about user `id`.

Comment: Thank you.. I just want to clarify a piece of information, which is that this program will be for registering members.. It is likely that there will be more than a thousand registered people and all of them will be able to modify their profiles.. ID number 14 is one member among many registered members.

Comment: When I save the information, it does not appear in the database

Comment: @mgaliazzi When I save the information, it does not appear in the database [link](https://imgur.com/a/4FBXZ9H)

Comment: pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (id='<built-in function id>')' at line 1")

Comment: @OualidBoukouja you have to read the `id` value, just as you did the other values.